# How to scrape a JavaScript-rendered page without Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have to scrape a JavaScript-rendered page in Python, but without Selenium. It must work for any pages, and I haven't found a proper way to that. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[requests-HTML](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/)** uses [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) to render JavaScript.

It will download Chromium in your home directory the first time you run render.

```
r = session.get('http://python-requests.org/')
r.html.render()
r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')['months'] '<time>25</time>'
```

Source: [Documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/)

Comment: the documentation link provided is for the 'Requests-HTML' package, not 'requests'

Comment: Correct link: https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/